# json_encode() UTF-8 error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some problem getting text with special characters (Swedish: "åäö") from the database.

If I just do a normal query,

```
"SELECT * FROM"
```

and the `echo` out the result:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['text']; 
}
```

... the result is fine.

However, when doing `json_encode($array)`, the special characters have been replaced:

```
{"id":"1","question":"fr\u00e5ga \u00e5\u00e4\u00f6"....
```

I don't know how many different things I tried, including converting the database to UTF-8, fields to `utf8_general_ci`, `utf8_encode($string)`, `utf8_decode($string)`, ....

Comment: those look like unicode character codes. Have you tried decoding the json array using php?

Comment: And you're doing 'SET NAMES utf8;' as well?

Comment: are you using mysql_set_charset when connecting to db ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: What do you get when it's displayed in the browser btw? Because the string just has Unicode escaped values in it which is not necessarily bad.

Comment: hm interesting there is a line feed encoded in the escaped JSON http://hexutf8.com/?q=u+00e5gau+00e5u+00e4u+00f6 I wonder if that is causing display issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is correct; that's how you're supposed to embed unicode characters in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But if this output is correct, then what do I have to do to make look right (plain text) in the browser?

Comment: You don't have to do anything; your browser or your javascript json library converts the escape codes into single characters.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design.
Those are JSON Unicode escapes.

Any compliant JSON parser will parse them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str='{"id":"1","question":"fr\u00e5ga \u00e5\u00e4\u00f6"}';
$obj=json_decode($str);
var_dump($obj);
```

Outputs this

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["question"]=>
  string(13) "fråga åäö"
}
```

So all is well - you're just seeing the JSON encoding of Unicode characters.

In PHP 5.4, you can pass [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://uk.php.net/json_encode#example-3444) to json_encode, and you'll get back JSON with UTF-8 encoded chars (at least I believe so - haven't tested that yet)